# Como obter o slug da página atual / para enfileiramento de scripts

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin, e gostaria de checar qual página do plugin está sendo visitada, pois tenho o objetivo de enfileirar os scripts conforme a página, pois atualmente percebi que todos os Scripts que fiz no ínicio do meu plugin, estão sendo chamados em outras paginas(submenus) do meu plugin, e também até mesmo em plugins de terceiros..

Penso que através do Slug, consigo então criar uma condição e enfileirar os scripts conforme este.

Caso exista uma maneira mais adequada, estou curioso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira de fazer isso é usar o gancho `admin_enqueue_scripts` para enfileirar os arquivos que você precisa. Esse gancho será passado por um `$hook_suffix` relacionado à página atual que está carregada.

```
function my_admin_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
/* .... */
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue');
```

Créditos:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/how-can-you-check-if-you-are-in-a-particular-page-in-the-wp-admin-section-for-e